# What are the problems/issues that I can face when working with threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

I have learned about the following problems that I can face when working with threads:

- When you write a value to a variable in memory, the value is not necessarily written to the memory location (the value can be written to cache), and so if another thread is reading this variable, it will not read the value that the other thread just wrote.
- Also, when you read from a variable in memory, the value is not necessarily read from the memory location (the value can be read from cache), and so if another thread wrote a value to this variable, and your thread is trying to read it, it will not read the value that the other thread just wrote.
- You need to be careful that some tasks needs to be "atomic", so for example if two threads are doing calculations on a variable, you must not allow these two threads to do their calculations at the same time (one thread must wait for the other thread to finish its calculations).
- The compiler and/or the CPU can execute your program instructions out of order.
- You can have a deadlock (if each thread is waiting for the other thread to signal it before continuing).

Are there other problems that I can face when working with threads?

Comment: google about RaceConditions

Comment: Functions need to be reentrant. The `C` standard library is fairly safe, with `strtok` being a notable exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you write a value to a variable in memory, the value is not necessarily written to the memory location (the value can be written to cache)

You're thinking about it at the wrong level of abstraction.  What you say is true, but it's mostly of interest to the developers of the programming language toolchain that you use.  From the perspective of an application developer, it's better to say that a value written to memory by one thread does not immediately become visible to other threads.

> The compiler and/or the CPU can execute your program instructions out of order

Better to say that, when one thread writes several values to memory in sequence, other threads do not necessarily see the new values appear in the same sequence.

Within any single thread, the compiler and the CPU both must insure that everything *appears* to happen in *program order*.

> ...some tasks needs to be "atomic", so for example if two threads are doing calculations on a variable, you must not allow these two threads to do their calculations at the same time

True again, but that's not enough information to be useful.  You need to know *when* and *why* two different threads can or can not do their calculations at the same time.

The key concept is *invariants*.  An invariant is any condition that is always assumed to be true.  E.g., if you are implementing a linked list structure, one invariant is that every "next" pointer either points to a member of the list or, to NULL.  If you are implemeting a ring of linked nodes, then one invariant says that if you follow the chain of "next" pointers far enough, it will always take you back to where you started.

It's often the case that there is no way to perform some operation without temporarily *breaking* an invariant.  E.g., you may be unable to insert something into some data structure without temporarily putting the structure into an invalid state.

You said, "some tasks needs to be 'atomic'".  Better to say, some tasks require *mutual exclusion* (mutexes) to prevent one thread from seeing an invariant in a temporarily broken state caused by the action of some other thread.

Comment: I have found out that I can use a Critical Section to enforce mutual exclusion in WinAPI. But how can I do the following: 1) ensure that when a thread writes a value to a variable, the value is written directly to memory (i.e. the other threads can see it), 2) how can I ensure that a set of instructions that I specify will be executed in the same order that I wrote them in?

Comment: @Christopher, Re (1) The answer depends on the _memory model_ of the system that you are working with.  If you were working in Java, I could tell you exactly where to look for a formal description of the Java memory model.  I don't know as much about C and C++, but _most_ systems will guarantee at least this much:  If thread A writes something to memory before unlocking some lock, and then thread B locks the _same_ lock, thread B will be able to see what thread A wrote.

Comment: Re (2), You can't---at least, not without resorting to tricks that are specific to your compiler/version, your operating system/version, and/or your processor.  Within any single thread, it does not matter.  The execution of any single thread will always have the same _effect_ as the code that you wrote.  Between threads, you must use mutex locks or other synchronization methods to ensure that threads can only see shared data structures in meaningful, consistent states.